# How to fix the error on command "mysql -v"

Tags: mysql, ruby, database, shell, command-line

Hi to all commandline/mysql experts,

I am having a error when typing the comman "mysql -v"

I got this:
`ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

What I am thinking is I need to update the code where `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` is located then point it to somewhere that is exists or alternative is to create a file mysqld.sock and place it in the directory `/var/run/mysqld/`.

But I don't know where to start. :C

Any idea will be much appriciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You should start by checking if the server is running or not.

Comment: Linux or mac?  What version of mysql?  How was it installed? Was it installed from source, packaged, brew or yum, apt-get, etc?  Do you have trouble connecting any other way?  New installation?  If you can answer those, I may be able to help you a little easier.

Comment: ubuntu/linux, `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.22, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2`, I also run this codes `apt-get install libmysql-ruby libmysqlclient-dev`,
`apt-get install mysql-client`,
`apt-get install mysql-server`, and this is my first installation of mysql. Thank you for your repose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off:

1. Are you trying to connect to a MySQL server running in your local machine? Check whether it's running with something like

   $> ps -efl | grep mysql | grep -v "grep"
2. Is it working and still you can't connect? Well, then you can check the socks and stuff in the file /etc/my.cnf
3. Are you trying to connect in a server not in your local page? Then you have to tell mysql where to (say you try to connect to a server located in 111.111.111.111:

   $> mysql -h 111.111.111.111

Comment: Yes it is running, and there is no file /etc/my.cnf